# Get a variable from a deep recursive loop in scheme

Tags: scheme

I have a deep recursive process that outputs a list when it finds a solution to the problem, but this list is created very deep recursively. This is the code:

```
(define (dfs start target)
  (define (dfs-helper start target path new-links final-path)
    (display final-path) (newline)
    (if (null? final-path)
       (if (or (null? new-links) (member start path)) '()
               (first-not-null (lambda (x)
                                 (if (= start target) (dfs-helper x target path '() (append path (list start))) (dfs-helper x target (append path (list start)) (get-neighbors x) final-path)))
                           (get-neighbors start))

       )
       final-path 
    )
 )
 (dfs-helper start target '() (get-neighbors start) '())
)
```

(I alologize for the strange formatting)

Anyway, this outputs the following:

```
...
()
()
(1 7 20 15 22 23 39 40 49 41 31 25 17 18 9 19 26 36 27 12 11 10 3 13 14 21 28 37 43 53 44 52 51 42 50 54 57 58 61 62 60 63)
7
```

It's that second from the last line that I need. As you can see, when I display 'final-path' I get what I want, but for some reason (I think because of all the recursive calls) the actual variable at the end is just 7, not the list of all the numbers I want. How can I get my code to output that second from the last line, so I can manipulate the list it returns?

Answer (score 3):

Oog... this code can be a bunch simpler.  Let me make some suggestions.

First, defining the helper inside of the parent function is not helping you; it makes it impossible to test independently; move it outside.

Next, it's not clear to me why you have two arguments, "path" and "final-path"; a one-line purpose statement would be *really* helpful here. Part of this is deciding what your function is supposed to return on failure.

Finally, you *really really* need some test cases that show what the thing is supposed to produce for simple inputs.

I realize that it's entirely possible that you're looking for a "quick fix"; I should tell you that a solution that throws a mutable variable on top of the other stuff going on would certainly not a get a good grade in my class...

Apologies in advance for my supercilious tone :).

Answer (score 0):

rather than displaying `final-path` with a newline as a print-out where you can't get to it, create a list as a member of your `dfs` object.  Then append onto that list member, and process that list on the return of `dfs`.  For instance:

```
(define (dfs start target)
  (define return-list '()) ;;add a return list here that you will process later
  (define (dfs-helper start target path new-links final-path)
    ;;(display final-path) (newline)
    (set! return-list (cons final-path return-list)) ;;so you are now "building up" the return list
    (if (null? final-path)
       (if (or (null? new-links) (member start path)) '()
               (first-not-null (lambda (x)
                                 (if (= start target) (dfs-helper x target path '() (append path (list start))) (dfs-helper x target (append path (list start)) (get-neighbors x) final-path)))
                           (get-neighbors start))

       )
       final-path 
    )
 )
 (dfs-helper start target '() (get-neighbors start) '())

 ;;process the return-list value to get the values you're wanting from it ...
 ;;I'm guessing there is something specific you're looking for, i.e., you can
 ;;filter out all the empty-list elements, single-value elements, etc.
)
```